# Why are constraints preferred over autoresizing in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, constraints

In Xcode, when using the autoresizing option for any type of object, things seem to stay where they're supposed to be while maintaining a proportional size to the scene. I generally just select the inside arrows in the autoresizing box and everything maintains adequate sizes and proportions. However, I've seen multiple times on tutorials, blogs and videos that using constraints is "the right way". Why would the use of constraints be better than autoresizing when autoresizing seems to work perfectly? Would any problem surge when using autoresizing if I work only on iPhone in portrait mode?

[image]

Comment: Autoresizing is the older way of doing things, and has been around for as long as I can remember. Autolayout is the "new" way and was designed to support both iOS and macOS. It's more flexible and powerful.

Answer (score 1):

Well there are a two reasons I think. The first is probably the most accurate, but might leave you feeling weird after. Because Apple is pushing it.  Usually when apple is backing a new tool in their api, its wise to follow because they will drop support for old things you get used to like Autoresizing. Kinda sucks I know.

The second (better) reason that Autolayout will let you write view components that you can reuse between many different screen sizes. Yea Autoresizing helps, but Autolayout gives you more control when the screen size makes a large change like from iPhone to iPad. I've written views that live in all my iphone/ipad/apple tv apps.

Comment: When you do this, do you make changes significant enough to change the overall layout? In your opinion, is messing with the size classes less time involved than just creating one view for tablet, one for non-tablet, and using a function that just automatically loads the appropriate one?
I've found size classes to require far more effort than reward.

Answer (score 1):

An important reason is to allow views showing text, such as labels or buttons with titles, to adapt to the text content and font.

The text content should change due to internationalization/localization.

The font can change if Apple changes the system font or if the user asks for larger text to make reading easier.

With proper application of auto layout, your layout can adapt to such changes and still look good. Without auto layout, you would need to manually alter the layout to accommodate such changes.